# YouTube iframe embed Violation: non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchstart' event

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, warnings, passive-event-listeners

I'm embedding a youtube iframe on my website that is throwing the following warnings in my console:

**[Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchstart' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952 base.js:4560**

**[Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 115ms www-embed-player.js:583**

I'm sure it's this component, as when I comment it out, the warnings stop. I would like to get rid of these warnings. How to do this?

```
<iframe width="100%" height="300px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wHcyxs6pGIk" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Can you add the code of how you are embedding the video

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same issue...

Comment: Have you solved this? I'm getting this error and when I do the embedded video gives a youtube error window... any idea?

Comment: No, haven't solved it yet.

Comment: Any progress on this? i have the same issue here

Answer (score 1):

I have been having the same error. This is the only post I've seen addressing the issue. In the link the warning gives it directs you to check out : [Github EventListenerOptions/explainer.md](https://github.com/WICG/EventListenerOptions/blob/gh-pages/explainer.md)

In the document it says the following:

> There are a few more complicated scenarios where the handler only wants to suppress scrolling under certain conditions, such as:
> ...
> A UI element (like YouTube's volume slider) which slides on horizontal wheel events without changing the scrolling behavior on vertical wheel events. Since there is no equivalent of "touch-action" for wheel events, **this case can only be implemented with non-passive wheel listeners**.

It seems this error is inevitable due to YouTube's volume slider.